# Is there a way to get aab file without using eas in expo

Tags: react-native, expo, android-app-bundle, eas

**I am Posting Answer here**
**Yes We Can make .aab file without eas in expo**

## Steps

1.Go to the root folder of your Expo project.

2.Now change the directory to android using **`cd android`**

3. Now write **`./gradlew bundleRelease`**

4.Congrats your .aab file will be built. You can find your bundle file in **'android/app/build/outputs/bundle/app-release.aab'** directory.